# Reference in latex document to part of Matplotlib (pgf) generated figure

Tags: labels, python, ref, matplotlib

I have a Python script which draws a plot similar to this:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

x = np.linspace(-2,2,10)
y = x**2

ax.plot(x, y, label='$x^2$', color="#07529a", linewidth=2.0) #  <--  \label this here ???

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
fig.savefig("../plot.pgf", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Now I include the figure with this lines in LaTeX:

```latex
\begin{figure}[h!]%
    \centering
    \input{plot.pgf}
    \caption{Plot info}
    \label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}
```

Furthermore, I would like to describe the plotted function and add a reference to the plotted line (something like this: `\ref{fig:plot:axplot}`  or this: [Use symbols with \label and \ref in custom legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72874/use-symbols-with-label-and-ref-in-custom-legend)). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, with explanation below.

[image: Sample output]

Python file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import numpy as np

rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['pgf.preamble'] = [ r'\newcounter{axes}',
                             r'\renewcommand{\theaxes}{(\arabic{axes})}'
r'\newcommand{\axeshead}{\refstepcounter{axes}\theaxes: }' ]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

x = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
y = x**2

ax.plot(x, y, label=r'\axeshead $x^2$\label{ax:x2}', color="#07529a", linewidth=2.0)

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
fig.savefig("plot.pgf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{axes}[figure]

\renewcommand{\theaxes}{(\arabic{axes})}
\newcommand{\axeshead}{\refstepcounter{axes}\theaxes: }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \input{plot.pgf}
  \caption{Plot info}
  \label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}

The graph \ref{ax:x2} in Figure~\ref{fig:plot}.

\end{document}
```

On the latex side, you need to set up a counter that may be used to refer to the axes.  I have done this with

```
\newcounter{axes}[figure]
```

which creates the counter `axes`, that is reset at each `figure`.  (Be careful, strictly it is reset each time the `figure` counter is stepped which is trigged by the `\caption` command.)

I introduce a command `\axeshead` which is inserted into the label of the `ax.plot` directive.  The definition steps the `axes` counter and prints a visible label, whose format is controlled by `\theaxes`.  These definition needs to be duplicate in the python file in the 'pgf.preamble'.  Now you can just place your `\label` command inside the `label` argument of `ax.plot` and `\ref`erence it your latex file.